# filebeat config option logging.files.permissions is not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I've followed the elastic docs and config filebeat.yml in a way so that filebeat.log permission should be 644. But, it is setting it to 640.
Could anyone please help to identify the reason for it?

Note - I am running Filebeat in a container.

Elastic Doc link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.8/configuration-logging.html#_logging_files_permissions

filebeat.yml

```
 logging.files:
      path: /logs
      name: filebeat.log
      keepfiles: 10
      permissions: 0644
      rotateeverybytes: 1000000
```

Inside filebeat container

```
bash-4.4$ ls -l logs/
-rw-r--r-- 1  65534 root     101 Oct 13 09:08 samplecontainer.log
drwxr-xr-x 3 161745 161745  4096 Oct 13 09:08 data
-rw-r----- 1 161745 161745  6169 Oct 13 09:08 filebeat.log
```

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/24555

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will follow this issue.